# Searching for Specific Sequence within Email Content (Webmail)

Tags: search, wildcard, thunderbird, webmail

I'm trying to find occurrences of a specific sequence of digits within the content of my emails. I only remember the digits "678," but I want to locate instances of a larger number that contains these digits, like "012345678." Unfortunately, my current email platform's search isn't yielding the desired results.
simple example :
"I search for '678,' but the number '012345678' never shows up in the results. Any ideas?"

Are there any email clients or search techniques that can help me achieve this type of search?
(third party webmail client ) Thanks for your HELP !

678,' but the number '012345678' never shows up in the results. Any ideas?"